# How to force train a model on GPU on Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a GAN model on Google Colab using Tensorflow. However, it takes a very very long time per epoch. I'm using Google Colab Pro Even though I chose T4 GPU as my runtime type [T4 GPU chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHl9X.png), I noticed that it's not using GPU at all.[Google Colab not using GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDwqq.png)

I was wondering how I can improve my runtime by somehow forcing it to use GPU.

I tried using

```
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
```

to wrap around my train function, but it still does not make any difference. Google only seems to bring up results on how to change the runtime to GPU in Colab.

Comment: Maybe you have run up computing resources?

Comment: In your second image the backend is GPU. You could test if TensorFlow sees a GPU with `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`. If the list is not empty, TF finds at least one GPU, and will use it. Maybe your GAN is too complex, or your data pipeline is not optimized?

Comment: I still have compute units and TF does find a GPU. I think maybe it's because my GAN uses a custom train and loss function? How do I optimize my data pipeline?